# Image info, from relationship nested within grid

Tags: ee2, relationships, grid, image

I have a grid field, which contains a relationship field. The related entries have an image field. I want to dig down to the image credit, description, etc.

Here's what I thought *ought* to work:

```
{grid_field}
    {grid_field:relationship}
        {grid_field:relationship:image_field}
            {credit}<br />
            {description}
        {/grid_field:relationship:image_field}
    {/grid_field:relationship}
{/grid_field}
```

It didn't work, and I've tried so many variations with syntax, etc., that I don't even want to try to post them all here. Suffice to say it's been a lot and I haven't hit on an answer yet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What type of field is "image_field"?

Comment: Have your tried something like: {image_field:credit} - 
It's really hard to tell help as since your "image_field" would have to be some sort of grid in itself to hold all that info.

Comment: It's just a standard File field type. Usually you can access the credit, description, etc., within the tag pair for the field (see documentation: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/file.html#variable-pair-usage). But I haven't hit a way to drill down to it in the scenario described above.